# primefaces rowexpansion not updated

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have an issue with primefaces to update a dataTable. The problem is, that after submiting the "change" button, the datatabel is not updated - not with ajax=false, not with update=... . Maybe anyone has an idea?

Note: button and datatable are in two different forms, but should not be a problem, works for another case in my project. And userOrders are loaded lazily, but i logged the list in bean, the data is correctly available.

```
<h:form rendered="#{orderModel.positions.size() > 0}">
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-edit" value="change" update=":table:orderDT, temp" action="#{orderModel.editOrder()}" rendered="#{orderModel.posChecked and orderModel.orderEditable}"/>
</h:form>

<h:form id="table" >
    <p:dataTable id="orderDT" rendered="#{orderModel.user.orders.size() > 0}" reflow="true" var="order" value="#{orderModel.userOrders}" selection="#{orderModel.tempOrder}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{order.id}" scrollable="true" style="margin: 20px">
         <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":table" listener="#{orderModel.onRowSelected}"/>
         <f:facet name="header">
               Getätigte Bestellungen
         </f:facet>
         <p:column style="width:16px">
                <p:rowToggler/>
         </p:column>
         <p:column headerText="Bestellnummer">
                 <h:outputText value="#{order.id}"/>
         </p:column>


         <p:rowExpansion>
                  <p:dataTable id="exp" var="pos" value="#{order.orderPositions}" reflow="true">
                            <p:column headerText="Anzahl">
                                <h:outputText value="#{pos.quantity}"/>
                            </p:column>
                  </p:dataTable>
         </p:rowExpansion>
     </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Hi, [mcve] please. Otherwise we should start guessing which is sort of not effective time wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it on my own: I adapted the `rendered="#{orderModel.user.orders.size() > 0}` to `rendered="#{orderModel.userOrders.size() > 0}` and **added lazyLoading**. Probbaly the first would be enough, but I think the accessed fields should be the same.